# Fill pdf form and insert image, without Pdftk

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

is there any possible way to not lose any content, when inserting an image into a filled pdf, i am using the fpdm.php script from [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) and works prettty good i might add. the pdfs i am using i pass them trough pdftk, as in `pdftk.exe insert.pdf output output.pdf` so they can be filled via php with out throwing errors

so my problem is this, i have a pdf template, which i use to fill it with an array passed from php, and output it to browser or server, and works ok, but when i try to insert an image into it, it inserts it, but loses all filled data, i need to retain that data. i cant use pdftk because im on a godaddy shared hosting plan, also setasign scripts works i know, but i am trying to find a way without buying anything yet.

i found [this stamper](https://github.com/binarystash/pdf-watermarker) which stamps ok but loses pdf data, all boxes get blanked, and also [this one](http://codecanyon.net/item/pdf-stamper/8548120) that places the image and loses all data too. setasign is doing some magic stuff right there

Comment: found my solution, convert pdf to image after being filled, add image to that image, then convert back, not the best solution, but works as expected.

Comment: I'm in the same case of you. Did you find a better way to manage it ? If not, can you share your actual code please ? Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mentioned scripts are using [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) in the background which simply doesn't modifes the original document but will allow you to recreate a completely new PDF document by importing another one page by page into reuseable structures (XObjects). Because form fields or other dynamic content like links or any other annotation type are not part of a pages content stream they will get lost.

The mentioned "magic" of the [SetaPDF products](https://www.setasign.com/products/) is, that they modify the original document. Because of this all content will retain.

Comment: thank you very much for your support here, but as for the moment i have succesfully done what i wanted, filling a pdf, placing a logo on top of it, and outputting to browser, no data lost, in any case in the near future, i will gladly buy seta sign packs, but for the moment no cash for that.